# Google Apps Script to Email Active Spreadsheet

Tags: email, google-apps-script, range, google-sheets

I found a script online that takes the current sheet, copies it to a temporary new spreadsheet, converts it to PDF and emails it.   I was able to get it working but trying to set it up so that it only sends a certain range.  Tried to play with it a bit but I am not a good coder by any stretch.  Alternatively I'd be interested also in figuring out how to get it to fit to 1 page PDF in landscape, convert without gridlines (my online research shows this ins't possible?) or even send as XLS.

```
// Simple function to send Weekly Status Sheets to contacts listed on the "Contacts" sheet in the MPD.

// Load a menu item called "Project Admin" with a submenu item called "Send Status"
// Running this, sends the currently open sheet, as a PDF attachment
function onOpen() {
  var submenu = [{name:"Send Status", functionName:"exportSomeSheets"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Project Admin', submenu);  
}

function exportSomeSheets() {
  // Set the Active Spreadsheet so we don't forget
  var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Set the message to attach to the email.
  var message = "Please see attached"; // Could make it a pop-up perhaps, but out of wine today

  // Get Project Name from Cell A1
  var projectname = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("A1:A1").getValues(); 
  // Get Reporting Period from Cell B3
  var period = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("B3:B3").getValues(); 
  // Construct the Subject Line
  var subject = projectname + " - Weekly Status Sheet - " + period;


  // Get contact details from "Contacts" sheet and construct To: Header
  // Would be nice to include "Name" as well, to make contacts look prettier, one day.
  var contacts = originalSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Contacts");
  var numRows = contacts.getLastRow();
  var emailTo = contacts.getRange(2, 2, numRows, 1).getValues();

  // Google scripts can't export just one Sheet from a Spreadsheet
  // So we have this disgusting hack

  // Create a new Spreadsheet and copy the current sheet into it.
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet to export");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var projectname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheet = originalSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);

  // Find and delete the default "Sheet 1", after the copy to avoid triggering an apocalypse
  newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();
  newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();

  // Make zee PDF, currently called "Weekly status.pdf"
  // When I'm smart, filename will include a date and project name
  var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
  var attach = {fileName:'Weekly Status.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

  // Send the freshly constructed email 
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments:[attach]});

  // Delete the wasted sheet we created, so our Drive stays tidy.
  DocsList.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To send a single sheet you may hide all other before sending.

```
var sheet_to_send = 'Sheet1';
//-----------------------------
var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheets = as.getSheets();
for(var i in sheets){
    if (sheets[i].getName()!=sheet_to_send){
        sheets[i].hideSheet();
    }
}
MailApp.sendEmail(email_to, email_subject, email_body, {attachments: SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()});
for(var i in sheets){
    if (sheets[i].getName()!=sheet_to_send){
        sheets[i].showSheet();
    }
}
```

If you have more sheets to send, you would filter them with a javascript object:

```
var sheets_to_send = {'Sheet1':1, 'Sheet3': 1};
...
// replace 
if (sheets[i].getName()!=sheet_to_send)
// by
if (!(sheets[i].getName() in sheet_to_send))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using this code to automatically send a google spreadsheet with email in pdf format. it works fine, but I need to customize the pdf by removing the grid lines and set display A4 . Is there a way ? thanks

```
Simple function to send Weekly Status Sheets to contacts listed on the "Contacts" sheet in the MPD.

// Load a menu item called "Project Admin" with a submenu item called "Send Status"
// Running this, sends the currently open sheet, as a PDF attachment
function onOpen() {
var submenu = [{name:"Invia", functionName:"exportSomeSheets"}];
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Invia PDF', submenu);  
}

function exportSomeSheets() {
 // Set the Active Spreadsheet so we don't forget
var originalSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
// Set the message to attach to the email.
var message = "Messaggio email";
// Get Project Name from Cell A1
var projectname = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("A1:A1").getValues(); 
// Get Reporting Period from Cell A2
var period = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("A2:A2").getValues(); 
// Construct the Subject Line
var subject = projectname;


// Get contact details from "Contacts" sheet and construct To: Header
// Would be nice to include "Name" as well, to make contacts look prettier, one day.
var emailTo = originalSpreadsheet.getRange("A3:A3").getValues();


// Create a new Spreadsheet and copy the current sheet into it.
var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Spreadsheet to export");
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var projectname = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
sheet = originalSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
sheet.copyTo(newSpreadsheet);

var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
Logger.log(aliases);
Logger.log(aliases[2]); //returns the alias located at position 0 of the aliases array


// Make zee PDF, currently called "Weekly status.pdf"
// When I'm smart, filename will include a date and project name
var pdf = DocsList.getFileById(originalSpreadsheet.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
var attach = {fileName:'Nome_allegato',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};

// Send the freshly constructed email 
GmailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {'from': aliases[2], attachments:[attach]});

// Delete the wasted sheet we created, so our Drive stays tidy.
DocsList.getFileById(newSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to split a spreadsheet up, you must first copy the parts into a temporary sheet and then copy that sheet into a new spreadsheet.

Here is my code to replace yours from 'Create spreadsheet...' to where you delete Sheet1 of the new spreadsheet.

```
  //variables firstRow & lastRow define the part of the sheet to copy
  //create new spreadsheet
  var newSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('Spreadsheet to export');
  //create temporary sheet to copy to new spreadsheet
  var tempSheet = originalSpreadsheet.insertSheet();
  //if header copy it
  if (sheet.getFrozenRows() > 0)
  {
    dataSheet.getRange( 1, 1, sheet.getFrozenRows() ).copyTo( tempSheet.getRange(1,1) );
  }
  //copy relevant data to temporary sheet
  dataSheet.getRange( firstRow, 1, lastRow - firstRow + 1 ).copyTo(tempSheet.getRange( sheet.getFrozenRows() + 1, 1 ));
  //copy temp sheet to new spreadsheet
  tempSheet.copyTo( newSpreadsheet );

  //delete Sheet1 in new spreadsheet
  newSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1').activate();
  newSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();

  //delete temp sheet
  originalSpreadsheet.setActiveSheet(tempSheet);
  originalSpreadsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
```