# Attach google spreadsheet as pdf to email

Tags: email, pdf, google-apps-script

I would like to create a PDF of a specific sheet (not necessarily the active one) and send it as an email attachment. I've borrowed and tried several code snippets, but none work correctly. I've searched and analyzed all the forums I can find, but I can't figure out the issue. I'm a novice programmer, so I like it simple. This snippet is intuitive to me, but it gives the following error: "We're sorry, no servers are currently available. Please wait a bit and try again." Debugger says that both pdf and attach are undefined.

```
var pdf = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
var attach = {fileName:'test.pdf',content:pdf, mimeType:'application/pdf'};
MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body, {attachments:[attach]});
```

Three things:

1. can you help me get the pdf/attachment function working properly?
2. can you help me modify it for a specific sheet (say, Sheet1)?
3. is it possible to make a pdf out a range on a sheet rather than the whole sheet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to apply methods of one Class to another that does not implement it. (e.g. `getAs()` isn't a `Spreadsheet` method.) When you're writing your script, pay attention to the autocomplete feature, which would have helped to avoid this error. See [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18007676/1677912) for more details about that.

Answers:

1. See [Google Apps Script to Email Active Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597322/google-apps-script-to-email-active-spreadsheet), which demonstrates how to generate a PDF from a sheet.
2. To isolate a single sheet, see ajb1970's answer to the same question. The idea here is to copy the sheet you're interested in into a new, temporary, spreadsheet - and then make your PDF from that.
3. To do this with a range, repeat step 2, but with the range you're interested in.

Comment: Okay, thanks for explaining that the new, temporary sheet is required. Knowing that, I borrowed the code from this post https://gist.github.com/ixhd/3660885 because I could follow the logic better. It worked! Is there any way to keep the gridlines from showing up on the PDF? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you [google that](http://goo.gl/P8vzSj)? Not much you can do from a script, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, many, many times. The best I could find was to make the gridlines that I don't want white (in the document, not the script). Crude work around, but it indeed worked. The white gridlines do not appear on the PDF.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't script white gridlines. It's these little things that drive us mad...

Answer (score 0):

Use getBlob not getBytes. Also you cant specify a specific sheet. Instead copy that sheet into a new spreadsheet, convert that one to pdf and later delete it.